# NestJS GeoJSON in mongoDB error on type field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, geojson

I am using NestJS and @nestjs/mongoose to create a schema that needs to store a GeoJSON coordinate. Below is the schema for the location schema which has a field labeled point, this stores the point schema

```
import { Prop, Schema } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
    
@Schema()
export class PointSchema {
    @ApiProperty()
    @Prop({
        type: String,
        enum: ['Point'],
        default: 'Point',
        required: true
    })
    type: string
  
    @ApiProperty({
        type: [Number, Number]
    })
    @Prop({
        type: [Number, Number],
        required: true,
    })
    coordinates: number[]
}

@Schema()
export class Location {
    @ApiProperty({
        type: PointSchema
    })
    @Prop({
        type: PointSchema
    })
    point: PointSchema

    @ApiProperty()
    @Prop()
    addressShort: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Prop()
    addressLong: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Prop()
    geohash: string;
}
```

The issue is that when I go to save a new location, I get an error stating that the point field cannot be converted into an object field, since it is a string.

*location.point.type: Cast to Object failed for value "Point" (type string) at path "point.type", location.point.type.coordinates: Path `point.type.coordinates` is required.*

I am not sure why this happens, but if instead I change the object shape right before saving it to match what the error wants

```
const newLocation:Location = {
    ...location,
    point: {
        type: newPlace.location.point
    }
}
```

Then it works and will save the GeoJSON coordinates in the type field of the point. I'm not sure why it is trying to save the entire point object inside the type field, and I am worried that this will not be indexable. Has anyone experienced this before or has worked with NestJS mongo db and tried to use GeoJSON objects? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share with us the code where you save a new location and anything related?

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose expects `type` as an object. In your implementation, it's defined as a string. You need to change it :

```
@Schema()
export class PointSchema {
    @ApiProperty()
    @Prop({
        type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point'],
            default: 'Point',
            required: true,
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
            required: true,
        },
    })
    point: {
        type: string;
        coordinates: number[];
    };
}
```

---

> I'm not sure why it is trying to save the entire point object inside the type field

The reason why it is trying to save the entire point object inside `type` is because of `enum` and `default` properties :

```
@Prop({
  type: String,
  enum: ['Point'], // only accepts 'Point' as a value
  default: 'Point', // defaults to 'Point' if value is not provided
  required: true
})
type: string
```

- These properties restrict the possible values for `type` field to only `'Point'`, and also sets the default value to `'Point'` if no value is provided.
- When you try to save `Location` with `point`, `type` is set to `'Point'` (which is a string value). **That's why you get error**.
- When you create a new object with just `type` and assign it, you are creating a new object that has the correct shape that `enum` and `default` properties expect. **That's why it works when you save**.

---

> and I am worried that this will not be indexable.

It depends on how you plan to query.

- If you plan to query based on the `type`, then having the entire `point` object saved in that field could make querying more difficult.
- If you don't plan to query based on `type`, then it may not matter.

As long as the type field is stored as a string and not as an object, it should be indexable.